# Code behind the wait timer

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me the code for this expression, `"Waiting for" + n + "Seconds"`
such that the text displays only once in the output and the variable `n` keeps changing.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you writing a console application, or web or windows?

Comment: Its a basically,Software Testing Automation script and the console used is NUnit

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Waiting for {0} seconds\r", i);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

And replace the Sleep() with something useful.

Comment: But then `i` doesn't relate to the passing time?

Comment: This will display the text 50 times. I think he wants it to be diplayed only once. I guess this can be done using `Console.Clear` before `Console.Write` or something similar?

Comment: Just like a Microsoft progress bar - every half second, the time to wait goes up by a second! ;-)

Comment: @Bernhof: It's an old DOS trick: '\r' instead of '\r\n', no need for a Clear().

Answer (score 0):

To correct Henk's answer and incorporate Bernhof's suggestion, this ought to do the trick:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("Waiting for {0} seconds\r", i);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

If you are planning on altering the interval of `Sleep` then be sure to change the text of `Write` appropriately; for instance, from `seconds` to `minutes` if you `Sleep` for `1000 * 60`.

But this is based on such a vague question (in terms of what is being used to achieve this other than C# and .NET) that it may well not even suite your environment - if that is the case then you will obviously need to make us aware so that we may elaborate on any initial suggestions.

Comment: Hi people,Console.Clear(); throws exception,is there another way of doing it.Using Console.Write("Waiting for {0} seconds\r", i); alone displays text 50 times, i only needs to display it only once with only i value being changed.                                                                                                               Thanks.

Comment: What is the exception detail?

Comment: Actually the console used is a NUnit console which is a tool for executing Automation scripts in software testing and the exception used is, "This script is failed due to exception, please see N-Unit log file for error details.
System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid."

Comment: Hm, maybe it is because the console output is being redirected by NUnit - in which case you would get this exception.

Comment: @Above: Then is there some other way of doing it, i mean without the use of Console.Clear();

Comment: @Henk: I guessed the OP had attempted with `\r` and still experienced undesired behaviour, given the comment which supplied the verbatim code - maybe there is more to this with the whole NUnit situation.

Comment: @above: yes i had already tried with \r but the line is repeating,is there any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Define Timer in Aspx Page and define it as Diabled and define the action of timer 
then make it enabled in code behind when you want to use it
example

```
<asp:Timer ID="tmeRedirect" runat="server" Enabled="False" Interval="1000">
        </asp:Timer>
```

and in code behind

```
    Protected Sub tmeRedirect_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles tmeRedirect.Tick
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
End Sub
```

onClick

```
    Protected Sub btnReg_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReg.Click
    tmeRedirect.Enabled = True
End Sub
```